# dplyr version 1.0.0: count function don't return the right number of observation

Tags: r, dplyr, count

Can someone explain to me how dplyr::count function works

I have this data

```
rankings <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-04-14/rankings.csv')
```

when i use

```
rankings %>% dplyr::count(title) %>% mutate(Count = sum(n))
```

i get

```
   title                       n Count
   <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Juicy                      18   535
 2 Nuthin’ But A ‘G’ Thang    14   535
 3 The Message                14   535
 4 Shook Ones (Part II)       13   535
 5 Fight The Power            11   535
 6 C.R.E.A.M.                 10   535
 7 93 ’Til Infinity            7   535
 8 N.Y. State Of Mind          7   535
 9 Dear Mama                   6   535
10 Jesus Walks                 6   535
```

whoever there are only one obs per title (N = 311)...

thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, I'm getting `Count` column of 311's. Try restarting your R session. VTC as not reproducible.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I was able to reproduce in a fresh R session with `dplyr_1.0.0`

Comment: Looks like a "bug" was introduced in 1.0.0 that will be rolled back in 1.0.1: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5298. The problem is you have a column named `n` in your data which is mixing up the `count()` function

Comment: @MrFlick My `dplyr` package version was 0.8.5, I'm updating and will get back to this. After updating it's version 1.0.1 so if there was a bug I wouldn't know. Anyway I will retract my VTC.